# Qt - How to convert QString to char (NOT char*)

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion

This seems like it should be a fairly simple thing to do, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it. Basically I just have a QString object that will always be one character (specifically a letter) long, and I need to convert it to a char to set it to an object in my class of that type. I know how to make it char*, with `QString("myTextHere").toStdString.c_str()`, but the object that the value needs to be set to isn't char*, it's char. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that the `std::string` representation is in a particular encoding - the multibyte UTF-8 encoding where one code point may require many `char` code units. So, to start with, how do you guarantee that the first code point in the string even is representable as a single UTF-8 character? Of course, you can always convert it to latin1 first, but I don't see you doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I found a way to convert the value without getting the error about QCharRef, I found if I use the `QString::at()` function to get the first index instead of `QString("myText")[0]`, and then use `toAscii()` on that value, it seems to work and produce the correct value I want. In other words, this is what I did:

```
char c = QString("A").at(0).toAscii();
```

Comment: If you want this solution to be generic, thus to work for any character, you must remember that `QChar` is a code unit in UTF-16 encoding, not a code point. Thus the `QChar` might be a part of a UTF-16 surrogate. This doesn't matter of course if all you want is a conversion to ascii, but it should be kept in mind.

Comment: giving error : no member named 'toAscii' in 'QChar'

Comment: By now it has been replaced by `QChar::toLatin1()` but given that `QString`s are basically the UTF-16BE encoding you should really check to see if `QString(`...`).at(0).isHighSurrogate()` is `true` and if so use `QChar::surrogateToUcs4(QString(`...`).at(0), QString(`...`).at(1))` (assuming you do have two `QChar`s {a *surrogate pair*} to work on) - or `QString(`...`).at(0).unicode()` otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

Use the index operator to get the first character of the string:

```
QString("myTextHere").toStdString()[0]
```

---

However, there is no need to convert to `std::string`, so the following is a better idea:

The main problem is that `QString` is in UTF-16 and contains `QChar`s, two-byte characters. If your character can be represented using latin-1 charset, you should use

```
char ch = QString("myTextHere")[0].latin1();
```

Otherwise you need a bigger type (NOTE: even this cuts non-BMP characters in half):

```
int i = QString("myTextHere")[0].unicode();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however when I tried this I got an error saying "cannot convert from 'QCharRef' to 'char'", is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls fixed and expanded.

Answer (score 2):

If you claim that this returns a char*:

```
QString("myTextHere").toStdString.c_str();
```

Then obviously, this will get the first character, which would be `char`:

```
QString("myTextHere").toStdString.c_str()[0];
```

It may not look pretty, and probably there are better ways of getting the first character, but by definition, this code should (probably *must*) work.

Comment: @thnkwthprtls Not only is it perfectly fine to accept your own answer, this answer is two worst of all the answers thus far, since it has three things wrong with it: 1. Forces re-encoding of a UTF-16 QString into a UTF-8 `std::string`. 2. Allocates said `std::string`. 3. Does not offer a way of dealing with non-latin1 characters that don't have a single code unit representation in UTF-8 and form an UTF-8 surrogate.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, use QString::operator[]. Using this on a QString will return a QCharRef, a helper class that is equivalent to a QChar. Since QChar is meant to support unicode characters there is only one further specification. From QChar in qt documentation (4.7):

> QChar provides constructors and cast operators that make it easy to
>   convert to and from traditional 8-bit chars. If you defined
>   QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII and QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII, as explained in the
>   QString documentation, you will need to explicitly call fromAscii() or
>   fromLatin1(), or use QLatin1Char, to construct a QChar from an 8-bit
>   char, and you will need to call toAscii() or toLatin1() to get the
>   8-bit value back.

My Qt build will not allow

`char c = QString("myTextHere")[0];`

and instead I would use

`char c = QString("myTextHere")[0].toAscii();`

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me in case you are getting error

> error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you
>   mean to call it with no arguments?

```
QString mystr = "mystring";
char myvar = mystr.toStdString().c_str()[0];
```